# dhclient command does not allocate ip address to my interface

Tags: networking, network-interface, dhcp, ip-address, dhclient

So I was trying to access a website through my browser but I couldn't.
So I issued the ifconfig command to see if there was something  wrong with the IP address
[image]

I noticed that the interface enp0s3 does not have an IP address. So I issued this command in vain:
[image]

Still nothing changed. So I decided to check the /etc/network/interfaces file to check the configuration of the interfaces. I was surprised to find this:
[image]

Does anyone know what might be the problem and how I can solve it?

---

I forgot to precise I am running ubuntu on virtual box. And it is unable to connect to my home router. (Other Pcs can) sorry.

Comment: Your screenshot shows `dhclient` broadcasting a `DHCPDISCOVER`, but not receiving any response. Without response, it can't assign a address. Is there a DHCP server running in the network connected to enp0s3? E.g., is it connected to a home router? If yes, which brand and model, and have you tried to configure this router to enable DHCP?

Comment: I forgot to precise I am running ubuntu on virtual box. And it is unable to connect to my home router. (Other Pcs can) sorry.

Comment: Thank you I have just solved the issue by starting a new virtual machine. Sometimes, life is simple :p

Answer (score 1):

This might be because you are running ubuntu on virtualbox. Could you go to the VM settings and check that the network mode is bridged, nat, or nats (giving it direct access to your external network, DON'T run anything malicious on this box)?
This might resolve the issue as it seems like you might have internal or host-only networking on preventing the OS's access to your router's DHCP server

Comment: Thank you I have just solved the issue by starting a new virtual machine. Sometimes, life is simple :p

Comment: Sometimes, it's way too simple to even comprehend. Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Nothing changed and it gives me this after saving the edited interfaces file.

Comment: ** (gedit:2125): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata:: gedit-encoding not supported.

Comment: Thank you I have just solved the issue by starting a new virtual machine. Sometimes, life is simple :p